# ios swift - table view cell dynamic height depending on device

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, standards

There are a lot of posts asking how to make table view cells height dynamic and I understand that I could do it through `HeightForRowAtIndexPath`.

My questions is whether this is good practice or not.

It seems like an unscalable solution to check for a device and hard code a height just to be able to take up more room on lets say an iPhone 6 plus.

Is this good practice, should it be done at all, or is there a better way?
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can possibly set a height for your `TableView` multiplied with a suitable fraction. Say you design the cell for iPhone 6 Plus with dimensions of 1242 × 2208 pixels(414 × 736 points). Now you can infer a heightRatio w.r.t your current running device like

```
let heightRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 736
```

So in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you may return the height as

```
return yourInterfaceBuilderCellHeight * heightRatio
```

Comment: Thank you all for all your answers. Thank you Mathews

Comment: **Updated for Swift 5:**

Just change the way `heightRatio` is calculated to:

`let heightRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 736`

Answer (score 0):

you should not suppose to hard code your code for height of tableview cell.

you should apply height with the perfect calculations of height of tableview cell

if you hard code your code may be problematic in future so better to have practice with dynamic size of each cell

Answer (score 0):

If your data remains static or not changed dynamically then hard code for `heightForRowAtIndexPath`(giving static height) is OK, but if data is changing then it is not good practice to do hard code. You need to calculate each row's height so the data can be fit in it.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is changing dynamically and you need to set tableview cell height depends on that data height then **Apple** gives solution for this.

Just set both tableview property as below example.

```
_tableViewOne.estimatedRowHeight = 50; //minimum row height
_tableViewOne.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

so it will take row **height according** to it's content.

> Don't use tableview's heightForRowAtIndexPath method otherwise above
>   code will not work (it will override those properties).

You don't need to do anything else for height. System will handle it.